# Django URLs: Getting Internal Server Error When render/httpresponse in live server but Working in local

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm new in Django . I have worked Django web site, and it's working successfully in the local host . But got Internal Server Error after moving into live when I put **training.example.com/about** but working **training.example.com** . And page templates using common header and footer html codes, static files are working correctly. So please help review and advice  on my bellow the file path and codes.

**File path :**

```
--- Meluxdj
    |-- MainApp
        | -- migrations
        | -- static
             | --MainApp
                 | --css                 
                 | --js              
                 | --fonts               
                 | --images     
                 
        | -- templates
                 | -- MainAPP
                         | -- index.html
                         | -- about.html
                         | -- base.html
             
        |  --admin.py
        |  -- apps.py
        |  -- urls.py
        |  --views.py
        |  --models.py
    
    |-- Mainproject
        |  -- asgi.py
        |  -- urls.py
        |  -- settings.py
        |  -- wsgi.py
    
    
    | -- manage.py
    | -- passenger_wsgi.py
    | -- db.sqlite3
```

**MainApp/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def Index(request):
    mydata = {'val':'hai data from function'}
    return render(request,'MainAPP/index.html',mydata)

def about(request):
    
    return render(request,'MainAPP/about.html')
```

**MainApp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.Index , name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

**Mainproject/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('MainApp.urls')),
]
```

**Images**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ABA.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HebXw.jpg)

Comment: You write `return render(request,'MainAPP/about.html',mydata)` but where does `mydata` come from here? Also looking at your directory structure there is no folder `MainAPP` in the templates directory rather `about.html` is directly in `templates`?

Comment: yes , I have seen it and changed it .  I will try it As your point  **directly in templates?**

Comment: Oh, you appear to have edited the directory structure you added to the question so now that is correct...

Comment: I have tried html pages directly in templates . But still getting Internal Server Error .

Comment: fix your images please